# How to extract .zip file in Microsoft Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have xx.zip file in SFTP location. I have to extract all files from xx.zip while processing xx.zip through logic app only.

Is there any function or feature in Logic App to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFTP connector has an action "**Extract folder**" - *This operation extracts an archive file into a folder (example: .zip).*

Checkout this documentation on SFTP connector which has the similar scenario

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sftp

Let me know if this helps.